# AWS's own example of submitting Pig job does not work due to issue with piggybank.jar

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-pig, amazon-emr

I have been trying to test out submitting Pig jobs on AWS EMR following Amazon's [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-pig-launch.html). I made the change to the Pig script to ensure that it can find the piggybank.jar as instructed by Amazon. When I run the script I get an ERROR 1070 indicated that one of functions available in piggybank cannot be resolved. Any ideas on what is going wrong?

**Key part of error**

```
2018-03-15 21:47:08,258 ERROR org.apache.pig.PigServer (main): exception 
during parsing: Error during parsing. Could not resolve 
org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT using imports: [, 
java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: <file s3://cis442f-
data/pigons3/do-reports4.pig, line 26, column 6> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070: Could not resolve org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

**The first part of the script is as follows:**

Line 26 referred to in the error is contains "EXTRACT("

```
register file:/usr/lib/pig/lib/piggybank.jar;
DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.EXTRACT;
DEFINE FORMAT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.FORMAT;
DEFINE REPLACE org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REPLACE;
DEFINE DATE_TIME org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.DATE_TIME;
DEFINE FORMAT_DT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.datetime.FORMAT_DT;


--
-- import logs and break into tuples
--
raw_logs =
  -- load the weblogs into a sequence of one element tuples
  LOAD '$INPUT' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);

logs_base =
  -- for each weblog string convert the weblong string into a
  -- structure with named fields
  FOREACH
    raw_logs
  GENERATE
    FLATTEN (
      EXTRACT(
        line,
        '^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"'
      )
    )
    AS (
      remoteAddr: chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray, time: chararray,
      request: chararray, status: int, bytes_string: chararray, referrer: chararray,
      browser: chararray
    )
  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original script from Amazon would not work because it relied on an older version of piggybank. Here is an updated version that does not need piggybank at all.

```
--
-- import logs and break into tuples
--

raw_logs =
  -- load the weblogs into a sequence of one element tuples
  LOAD '$INPUT' USING TextLoader AS (line:chararray);

logs_base =
  -- for each weblog string convert the weblong string into a
  -- structure with named fields
  FOREACH
    raw_logs
  GENERATE
    FLATTEN (
      REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(
        line,
        '^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"'
      )
    )
    AS (
      remoteAddr: chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray, time: chararray,
      request: chararray, status: int, bytes_string: chararray, referrer: chararray,
      browser: chararray
    )
  ;

logs =
  -- convert from string values to typed values such as date_time and integers
  FOREACH 
    logs_base 
  GENERATE 
    *, 
    ToDate(time, 'dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z', 'UTC') as dtime,
    (int)REPLACE(bytes_string, '-', '0')          as bytes
  ;


--
-- determine total number of requests and bytes served by UTC hour of day
-- aggregating as a typical day across the total time of the logs
--
by_hour_count =
  -- group logs by their hour of day, counting the number of logs in that hour
  -- and the sum of the bytes of rows for that hour
  FOREACH 
    (GROUP logs BY GetHour(dtime))
  GENERATE 
    $0, 
    COUNT($1) AS num_requests, 
    SUM($1.bytes) AS num_bytes
  ;

STORE by_hour_count INTO '$OUTPUT/total_requests_bytes_per_hour';



--
-- top 50 X.X.X.* blocks
--
by_ip_count =
  -- group weblog entries by the ip address from the remote address field
  -- and count the number of entries for each address blok as well as
  -- the sum of the bytes
    FOREACH
      (GROUP logs BY (chararray)REGEX_EXTRACT(remoteAddr, '(\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)', 1))
  --     (GROUP logs BY block)
    GENERATE  $0,
      COUNT($1) AS num_requests,
      SUM($1.bytes) AS num_bytes
  ; 



by_ip_count_sorted =  ORDER by_ip_count BY num_requests DESC;

by_ip_count_limited =
  -- order ip by the number of requests they make
  LIMIT by_ip_count_sorted 50;

STORE by_ip_count_limited into '$OUTPUT/top_50_ips';


--
-- top 50 external referrers
--
by_referrer_count =
  -- group by the referrer URL and count the number of requests
  FOREACH
    (GROUP logs BY (chararray)REGEX_EXTRACT(referrer, '(http:\\/\\/[a-z0-9\\.-]+)', 1))
  GENERATE
    FLATTEN($0),
    COUNT($1) AS num_requests
  ;

by_referrer_count_filtered =
  -- exclude matches for example.org
  FILTER by_referrer_count BY NOT $0 matches '.*example\\.org';

by_referrer_count_sorted =
  -- take the top 50 results
  ORDER by_referrer_count_filtered BY $1 DESC;

by_referrer_count_limited =
  -- take the top 50 results
  LIMIT by_referrer_count_sorted 50;

STORE by_referrer_count_limited INTO '$OUTPUT/top_50_external_referrers';


--
-- top search terms coming from bing or google
--
google_and_bing_urls =
  -- find referrer fields that match either bing or google
  FILTER
    (FOREACH logs GENERATE referrer)
  BY
    referrer matches '.*bing.*'
  OR
    referrer matches '.*google.*'
  ;

search_terms =
  -- extract from each referrer url the search phrases
  FOREACH
    google_and_bing_urls
  GENERATE
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(referrer, '.*[&\\?]q=([^&]+).*')) as (term:chararray)
  ;

search_terms_filtered =
  -- reject urls that contained no search terms
  FILTER search_terms BY NOT $0 IS NULL;

search_terms_count =
  -- for each search phrase count the number of weblogs entries that contained it
  FOREACH
    (GROUP search_terms_filtered BY $0)
  GENERATE
    $0,
    COUNT($1) AS num
  ;

search_terms_count_sorted =
  -- order the results
  ORDER search_terms_count BY num DESC;

search_terms_count_limited =
  -- take the top 50 results
  LIMIT search_terms_count_sorted 50;

STORE search_terms_count_limited INTO '$OUTPUT/top_50_search_terms_from_bing_google';
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct function name is [REGEX_EXTRACT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/api/org/apache/pig/builtin/REGEX_EXTRACT.html). So either change your `DEFINE` statement to

```
DEFINE EXTRACT org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.REGEX_EXTRACT;
```

OR use `REGEX_EXTRACT` directly in your pig script

```
logs_base =
-- for each weblog string convert the weblong string into a
-- structure with named fields
  FOREACH
    raw_logs
  GENERATE
    FLATTEN (
      REGEX_EXTRACT(
        line,
        '^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\[([\\w:/]+\\s[+\\-]\\d{4})\\] "(.+?)" (\\S+) (\\S+) "([^"]*)" "([^"]*)"'
      )
    )
    AS (
      remoteAddr: chararray, remoteLogname: chararray, user: chararray, time: chararray,
      request: chararray, status: int, bytes_string: chararray, referrer: chararray,
      browser: chararray
    )
  ;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. It got me to look more deeply into the problem. It appears that the functions included in piggybank have changed over the years. The one this script does not have the same name and may or may not work in the same way as the version currently part of AWS EMR. In the end I found out that the  REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL built-in function works in this application. . . . now on to figuring out the DATE_TIME function that is  no longer in piggybank :o)   Thanks again.